# Apply style on Iframe from cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain, iframe-resizer

I have a widget which is loading by iframe.
Can I change style for inner content ?

I used Following plugin to try :
 https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/tree/master/example

```
jQuery('#market_quotes_f').iFrameResize({
    log : true,                  // Enable console logging
    autoResize: false,
    enablePublicMethods: true,
    sizeWidth: true     
});
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You can only change the styles in the iFrame, from the parent page, if both are hosted on the same domain. Or you control both domains.

The iframe-resizer script you are using requires that you place JS files on both the host page and the child page in the iFrame. If you have done this then why not just add a CSS file to the iframe content?